# Error: Account is Not Allowed To Suggest Edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

[image: Error message while trying to edit SuperUser post on the iOS mobile app.]

I get this message while trying to edit a post on SuperUser while using the iOS mobile app. I have at least 101 reputation on SU, more than enough to be able to edit posts. This appears to be a bug.

Comment: Does this still happen? There was no competing edit or something like that?

Comment: @Bart Yep, still the same problem as of right now.

Comment: Can you suggest edits *via the Super User website*? Also, note that the iOS app now asks you to post bugs on [metase] (but it'll be found here too).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can edit posts on the website, but cannot edit on any site in the app.

Comment: Apparently this is [tag:status-bydesign] as the API does not support suggested edits at all (so the android app has the same limits)